# How to properly paginate in API for Oracle Fusion Cloud HCM?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am using the [REST API for Oracle Fusion Cloud HCM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/human-resources/23a/farws/op-learnerlearningrecords-get.html) which is returning me data in a paged manner. Though now I am stuck on how I get the next batch.

Here is a screenshot of the data I am getting from the very first call:

[image: Dump of the data returned by the first call to the API]

Here is my code

```
<cfparam name="variables.offset" default="0">
<cfparam name="variables.limit" default= "25">
<cfparam name="variables.hasMoreData" default="true">

…

<cfif variables.hasmoreData eq true>
    <cfset variables.offset = variables.resultData.data.offset + 1>
    <cfset variables.limit = variables.resultData.data.totalResults - variables.resultData.data.limit>
</cfif>
```

The problem seems to be in the bottom section where I am unable to determine the next offset to get the next batch until it reaches the end of the total records.

Comment: We would need to know the documentation for the API you're calling.  (It's not clear if it's an API you've written that you're accessing or if it's an external API that you're calling.)


I would suggest that if you're calling an API and sending offset/limit values, that if offset=0 is the first page, then offset+limit would be the next page.  0,25 gets you records 1 to 25, next page sending 25,25 resulting in rows 26 - 50.

Comment: its this api: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/human-resources/23a/farws/op-learnerlearningrecords-get.html

Comment: Two side notes regarding your code: First, the three variables don't seem to be parameters, so you can also initialize them via `<cfset>` instead of `<cfparam>`. _If_ they are parameter which should be changable from outside your script, you should add `type` attributes to your `<cfparam>`s and use a different scope, e.g. `url`. Second, you can normally skip the `variables` scope prefix, i.e. you may just write `offset` instead of `variables.offset`, for example.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that being explicit about your scopes is a good practice. It ensures that you're accessing a variable in a specific scope and avoids scope searching. It's also more performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API obviously uses the parameters `offset` and `limit` to paginate the returned data.

`offset` is zero-based and defines the starting position of the returned data. And `limit` restricts the maximal number of returned results and by that represents the number of items per page.

So setting `offset` to `offset + 1` for the next call is wrong. You need to increase it by the batch size, i.e. you need to add `limit` to it. As the number of items per batch normally isn't expected to change, `limit` should stay unchanged.

Therefore, the code to increase the offset might rather look like this:

```cfml
<cfset variables.hasMoreData = variables.resultData.data.offset lt variables.resultData.data.totalResults>
<cfif variables.hasMoreData>
    <cfset variables.offset = variables.resultData.data.offset + variables.resultData.data.limit>
</cfif>
```

Comment: In case it's not clear, to the OP, you don't want to send a new offset of offset+1, you want offset=(last)offset+limit.  I think you have it.  I was just looking at your original post.

Comment: I've explained a bit more to make it clear why it's `offset + limit`.

Comment: i tried the things you guys mentioned, i had faced an issue with it, i am getting 6000 records while in the environment it has 20000 records

Comment: Then maybe your pagination is still incorrect (e.g. your steps regarding the offsets are too wide) or there's a limitation for fetching the data or something else related to fetching the data is incorrect. You need to debug your code to find the reason for the discrepancy. First, you should check the offsets. If you use a limit of 25, then the offsets should be 0, 25, 50, 75, etc. If that's the case, check whether you get entries when you choose an offset larger than 6000. You should also check whether you get overlapping data when the choosing 0 and 24 as offsets.